# Java 8 internal iteration

Tags: java, java-8

Is the internal iteration executed only with the `forEach` method of a `Collection`
object or also with `Stream`'s methods like `filter`, `reduce`, etc. ?

Comment: Is this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219667/stream-and-lazy-evaluation)?

Comment: Yes, I' d like to know if methods like i.e. sum too use an internal iteration.

Comment: `sum` is a terminal operation, so yes it does iterate... If you are really interested in the internals of the streams api you should inspect the code...

Comment: @assylias, where can I see the implementation code of sum?

Comment: Download jdk 8 (comes with source), write code using sum, run in debug mode and step into the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should first define what you understand by the term “external iteration”. Since you don’t program a loop when invoking `filter`, `map`, or `reduce`, it’s not an external iteration by definition.

You may try to change your point of view and look inside the `filter`, `map`, or `reduce` methods. But it’s not necessarily useful to look at an implementation when trying to understand the *concept*.

When performing `filter`, `map`, or `reduce` you are defining an operation in terms of `Predicate`, `Function`, `BiFunction`, or `BinaryOperator`. And none of them will implement a loop using an `Iterator` therefore it’s still not an external loop.

It seems that you want to know whether the iteration code happens to be inside the `Collection` class or within the `Stream` class but that’s an unimportant implementation detail as these are parts of the same library/framework and hence the iteration is to be considered “internal” regarding this library/framework in either case.

Even the third option, having another party, the `Spliterator` performing the loop doesn’t change the nature of the iteration. It’s typical for an *internal iteration* that you can’t see at the first glance where the iteration actually happens.

Answer (score 5):

Fundamentally to operate on all the members of a collection something needs to iterate over them.

The exact way it does that may change based on the collection and the operation but the fact that it needs to happen is inescapable.

Comment: +1 ArrayList can avoid creating an Iterator, but it still iterates over the elements.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of whether the iteration is internal or external.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that question was never asked. The question was whether it is executed only for forEach or whether it is executed on the others too - and the answer is that some form of iteration is needed for things like filter/reduce...

Comment: @TimB: In the comments to the question, the OP asked "I'd like to know if methods like i.e. sum too use an internal iteration," which does still sound to me like he's asking about internal versus external iteration.  I've removed the downvote, but I do still think you're misinterpreting the question.

Comment: Ahh, that comment was added after I replied I think.

Answer (score 1):

There is internal iteration as pointed by [@Tim B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21313711/270349) but not all items are always processed. There is filtering and short-circuiting when you chain several operations to avoid unnecessary computation.

Reference [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

Answer (score 1):

Stream operations are based on top of [`Spliterator`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html)s, which are a weird mix somewhere between internal and external iteration.  A `Spliterator` is an external object returned by the collection's `spliterator()` method, but the `Spliterator` itself accepts callbacks to pass the methods to, like internal iteration would.

For example, `collection.stream().forEach(consumer)` would be (essentially) equivalent to `collection.spliterator().forEachRemaining(consumer)`, or it might be used like

```
Spliterator<T> spliterator = collection.spliterator();
while (spliterator.tryAdvance(consumer)) {
   // do something
}
```