# find smallest positive number in an array

Tags: java

So ... I have : int array[] = {-8,2,0,5,-3,6,0,9};

I want to find the smallest positive number ( which in the list above is 2 )

This is what i am doing :

---

```
int array[] = {-8,2,0,5,-3,6,0,9};

int smallest=0;


        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) // Find the first number in array>0 (as initial           
                                         // value for int smallest)
        {
            if(array[i]>0)
            {
                smallest=array[i]; 
                break;// Break out of loop, when you find the first number >0
            }   
        }


        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) // Loop to find the smallest number in array[]
        {

            if(smallest>array[i]&&array[i]>0)
            {
                smallest=array[i];

            }

        }

        System.out.println(smallest);

        }
```

---

My question is :

Can we reduce the number of steps ? 
Is there any smarter/shorter way of doing it, with no other data structure.

Thanks.

Comment: You can sort the array using Arrays.sort and then take the first or last item as you need.

Comment: That will give -8, not 2, in the example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/java-max-min-value-in-an-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to have `smallest=array[i]`, just initialize a variable with `INTEGER.MAX_VALUE` or `array[0]` and iterate over the array comparing the value with this variable.

This is achieved in **O(n) time** and **O(1) space** and thats the best you can get! :)

a simpler way would be

```
 int[] array ={-1, 2, 1};
 boolean max_val_present = false;  

 int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

 for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) // Loop to find the smallest number in array[]
 {
      if(min > array[i] && array[i] > 0)
         min=array[i];
      //Edge Case, if all numbers are negative and a MAX value is present
      if(array[i] == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        max_val_present = true;
 }

 if(min == Integer.MAX_VALUE && !max_val_present) 
 //no positive value found and Integer.MAX_VALUE 
 //is also not present, return -1 as indicator
    return -1; 

 return min; //return min positive if -1 is not returned
```

Comment: You still return an INTEGER.MAX_VALUE when all items are non-positive.

Comment: @SeyfülislamÖzdemir : good point, updated code..thanks fella! :)

Comment: Now you return -1 when the input is an array which contains only non-positive numbers and at least one INTEGER.MAX_VALUE. You should return an INTEGER.MAX_VALUE for such a case. :)

Comment: @SeyfülislamÖzdemir : Edge cases.. :) updated code, validate now! :)

Comment: Why min <= array[i]? If min == array[i] there is no point of assign min=array[i]. I would change it with min < array[i].

Comment: Still it won't work. "min <= array[i]" is wrong. It will return 2 for the array [-1, 2, 1]. If you make it >= the function will return -1. :)

Comment: Have you tested your code with an array like this? `{8,2,0,5,-3,6,0,9}` ?

Comment: Your edit is wrong. You cannot initialize `array[0]` as the initial `smallest`, since it might be negative. (Please revert and downvote will be removed)

Comment: @amit : reverted back to original logic, updated and it works..mind taking back the downvote?? :)

Comment: @SeyfülislamÖzdemir : updated and its working well... ;)

Comment: Think it works now. :) If it does not, in case, I don't check as you wouldn't handle one more comment which tells you your errors. :P

Comment: @SeyfülislamÖzdemir : nope..its works now...i checked...if u find a bug, most welcome to let me know!! :)

Answer (score 6):

> is there any smarter/shorter way of doing it?

If you want shorter, with Java 8, you can use a stream of ints:

```
int min = Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i >= 0).min().orElse(0);
```

(assuming you are happy with a min of 0 when the array is empty).

Comment: so much overhead for a so simple task

Comment: How do you handle the only positive numebrs limiation without adding a filter, which practically means another iteration?

Comment: @assylias Is it optimized to overcome the slow-down of multiple iterations?

Comment: @amit there will only be one iteration.

Comment: @assylias Really? I am not fluent in java8, but I figured out it will create a stream of all elements that match the filter condition, and than iterate them to yield the min. Nice to know it is optimized to do it in a single iteration. Is it implementation detail or written in specification? (Not sarcastic comment, truly am impresses)

Comment: @amit it is by [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html): *"Laziness-seeking. Many stream operations, such as filtering [...] can be implemented lazily, exposing opportunities for optimization. For example, "find the first String with three consecutive vowels" need not examine all the input strings. Stream operations are divided into intermediate (Stream-producing) operations and terminal (value- or side-effect-producing) operations. **Intermediate operations are always lazy**."*. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/21223645/829571.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou on my machine, the stream version takes respectively 65, 200 and 50000 nanoseconds for arrays of 10, 100, 10000 elements, vs. 20, 125, 48000 for the "manual" version. So there is an overhead but it is not very high and decreases in % as the size of the array increases.

Answer (score 3):

Without any prioe knowledge there is no way to avoid iterating the entire array.

You can however make sure you iterate it only once by removing the first loop, and instead just assign [`smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). You can also add a boolean that indicates the array was changed to distinguish between cases where there is no positive integer, and cases where the only positive integer is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: 50sec behind...i am getting old!! :)

Comment: Wondering who downvoted this answer. Please provide a comment why this answer is wrong.

Comment: not really sure who downvoted you..but may be lack of code might be reason (*i too hate those kind of visitors*) :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I really prefer words over code in many situations, as it lets the OP understand the answer, and implement it by his own. I hope this is not the issue :|

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two loops for this purpose.

```
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    if(array[i] > 0 && smallest > array[i])
    {
        smallest = array[i]; 
    }  
}
```

The only problem with this code is that after the loop you can't know that whether all elements are non-positive or at least one of them is Integer.MAX_INT and remaining is non-positive. You should add controls if you think that such a case is possible.

Answer (score 0):

A sample for you:

```
    int array[] = {-8,2,0,5,-3,6,0,9};
    int minPosNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] > 0 && array[i] < minPosNum){
            minPosNum = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(minPosNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[] = {-8,2,0,5,-3,6,0,9};
int minPos = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (int number : array) {
    if (number > 0)
        minPos = Math.min(number, minPos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to do it with 1 loop:

```
int array[] = {8,2,0,5,-3,6,0,9};
int smallestPositive = array[0];

for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
    if(smallestPositive > 0){
        if(array[i] < smallestPositive && array[i] > 0)
            smallestPositive = array[i];
    }else
        smallestPositive = array[i];
}
```

`System.out.println(smallestPositive);` will print `2`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
import java.util.*;
public class SmallItem 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       int array[] = {-8,2,0,5,-3,6,0,9};
       int number = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
       ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

       //Here we add all positive items into a ArrayList al
       for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){
           if(array[i]>0){
               al.add(new Integer(array[i]));
           }
       }

       Iterator it = al.iterator();
       while(it.hasNext()){
           int n = ((Integer)it.next()).intValue();
           if(n<number){
               number = n;
            }
        }
       System.out.println("Smallest number : " + number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For C++

```
int smallest (int array[]){
    int a;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(array[i]>0){
            a=array[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(array[i]<=a && array[i]>0){

            a=array[i];
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Please add a line of explanation for the code you have provided

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript

```
var inputArray = [-1,2,1,5,-20];
var arrayWithOnlyPositiveValue = [];

    for(var i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++){

        if(inputArray[i]>=0){
            arrayWithOnlyPositiveValue.push(inputArray[i])
            }

    }

    var min_of_array = Math.min.apply(Math, arrayWithOnlyPositiveValue);
    console.log('---smallestPositiveValue----',min_of_array);
```

Comment: you are effectively looping twice

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = { -1, 2, 1, -2, 11, 23, 44 };
            int min = MinArray(array);
            Console.WriteLine(min.ToString() + " is the minimum number!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static int MinArray(int[] array)
        {
            int minimumNumber = Int32.MaxValue;
            foreach (int i in array)
            {
                if (i < minimumNumber && i > 0)
                {
                    minimumNumber = i;
                }

            }

            return minimumNumber;
        }
    }
}
```