# Java 8 stream operations execution order

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
List<Integer> twoEvenSquares = numbers.stream().filter(n -> {
    System.out.println("filtering " + n);
    return n % 2 == 0;
}).map(n -> {
    System.out.println("mapping " + n);
    return n * n;
}).limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList());


for(Integer i : twoEvenSquares)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

when executed the logic below output came

```
filtering 1
filtering 2
mapping 2
filtering 3
filtering 4
mapping 4
4
16
```

if the stream follows the short circuit concept (where we use limit stream operation), then output must be like below:

```
filtering 1
filtering 2
filtering 3
filtering 4
mapping 2
mapping 4
4
16
```

because after filtering 2, we have to still find one more element to stratify limit(2), operation,  so why the output is not coming like I explained?

Comment: Why "must" it be like the second? Because it shouldn't (and isn't).

Answer (score 33):

Streams are pull-based. Only a terminal operations (like the `collect`) will cause items to be consumed.

Conceptually this means that `collect` will ask an item from the `limit`, `limit` from the `map` and `map` from the `filter`, and `filter` from the stream.

Schematically the code in your question leads to

```
collect
  limit (0)
    map
      filter
        stream (returns 1)
      /filter (false)
      filter
        stream (returns 2)
      /filter (true)
    /map (returns 4)
  /limit (1)
  limit (1)
    map
      filter
        stream (returns 3)
      /filter (false)
      filter
        stream (returns 4)
      /filter (true)
    /map (returns 16)
  /limit (2)
  limit (2)
  /limit (no more items; limit reached)
/collect
```

And this conforms to your first printout.

Comment: Do you know of any tools that are able to take stream-based code and translate it into output like this? I tried to ask a question about that, but it was deemed off-topic.

Comment: @MattPassell No, sorry.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As your answer and @Umberto answer do not match,  please confrim if `collect` would be called after `limit` reaches 2 or for every `limit` call. I asked him but, yet to receive reply...

Comment: @San From my answer _"Only a terminal operations (like the `collect`) will cause items to be consumed."_. There is only **one** limit call, the schema in my answer is to illustrate the concept, the `limit (0)` etc in that schema is not a method invocation, it represents the stream the `collect` method is called on, and the current number of items consumed when the `collect` method pulls a value out of the stream. The _method_  `limit(n)` is an intermediate operation that will return a stream that emits at most `n` items. If you need more, consider asking a new question, link for context.

Comment: @San IOW, each intermediate operation transforms the stream it was called on into another stream. Only terminal operations consumes items from a stream, and when doing that each intermediate stream will get on or more items from the 'up'stream. So collect asks an item from the `limit` stream, which will ask one from the `map` stream, which will ask one from the `filter` stream, which will then ask two items from the original `stream` (two because the first one doesn't pass the filter), and so on until the maximum items from `limit` has been reached (or the 'up'streams have run out of items).

Answer (score 16):

This is the result of the *lazy execution/evaluation* of intermediate stream operations.

The chain of operations is lazily evaluated in reverse order going from `collect()` to `filter()`, values are consumed by each step as soon as they are produced by the previous step.

To describe more clearly what's happening:

1. The only terminal operation `collect()` starts the evaluation of the chain.
2. `limit()` starts the evaluation of its ancestor
3. `map()` starts the evaluation of its ancestor
4. `filter()` starts consuming values from the source stream
5. `1` is evaluated, `2` is evaluated and the first value is produced
6. `map()` consumes the first value returned by its ancestor and produce a value too
7. `limit()` consume that value
8. `collect()` collect the first value
9. `limit()` requires another value from the `map()` source
10. `map()` requires another value from it's ancestor
11. `filter()` resume the evaluation to produce another result and after evaluating `3` and `4` produce the new value `4`
12. `map()` consumes it and produce a new value
13. `limit()` consume the new value and returns it
14. `collect()` collects the last value.

From the [java.util.stream docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> Stream operations are divided into intermediate and terminal
>   operations, and are combined to form stream pipelines. A stream
>   pipeline consists of a source (such as a Collection, an array, a
>   generator function, or an I/O channel); followed by zero or more
>   intermediate operations such as Stream.filter or Stream.map; and a
>   terminal operation such as Stream.forEach or Stream.reduce.
>
> Intermediate operations return a new stream. **They are always lazy**;
>   executing an intermediate operation **such as filter() does not actually
>   perform any filtering**, but instead creates a new stream that, when
>   traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the
>   given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source **does not begin until
>   the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed**.

Comment: As `limit` has not reached its limit of 2, will step 8 be called? In other words, will `collect` operation hold first value after step 7.

Comment: Anybody, FYI: A good explanation for excerpt text in **bold** can be found in answers to [Stream and lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219667/stream-and-lazy-evaluation) post . My lazy cents.

Answer (score 4):

The `Stream` API is not meant to provide guarantees regarding order of the execution of the operations. That’s why you should use side-effect free functions. The “short circuiting” does not change anything about it, it’s only about not performing more operations than necessary (and completing in finite time when possible, even for infinite stream sources). And when you look at your output you’ll find that everything works right. The performed operations match the ones you expected and so does the result.

Only the order doesn’t match and that’s not because of the *concept* but your wrong assumption about the *implementation*. But if you think about how an implementation which does not use an intermediate storage has to look like, you will come to the conclusion that it has to be exactly like observed. A `Stream` will process each item one after another, filtering, mapping and collecting it before the next one.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you noticed is the correct one. In order to find out if a number passes the entire Stream pipeline, you have to run that number through all the pipeline steps.

```
filtering 1 // 1 doesn't pass the filter
filtering 2 // 2 passes the filter, moves on to map
mapping 2 // 2 passes the map and limit steps and is added to output list
filtering 3 // 3 doesn't pass the filter
filtering 4 // 4 passes the filter, moves on to map 
mapping 4 // 4 passes the map and limit steps and is added to output list
```

now the pipeline can end, since we have two numbers that passed the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

`filter` and `map` are intermediate operations. As the doc states:

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy;
>   executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually
>   perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when
>   traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the
>   given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source **does not begin** until
>   the **terminal** operation of the pipeline is **executed**.
>
> [...]
>
> Processing streams lazily allows for significant efficiencies; in a  pipeline such as the filter-map-sum example above, filtering, mapping, and summing can be fused into a single pass on the data, with minimal intermediate state.

So when you call your terminal operation (i.e `collect()`), you can think of something like this (this is really simplified (you'll use the collector to accumulates the pipeline's content, Streams are not iterable, ...) and does not compile but it's just to visualize things):

```
public List collectToList() {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    for(Elem e : this) {
        if(filter.test(e)) { //here you see the filter println
            e = mapping.apply(e); //here you see the mapping println
            list.add(e);
            if(limit >= list.size())
                break;
         }
     }
     return list;
 }
```