# order of execution of map().map() in Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I use the following code (simplified):
in main:

```
Foe[] foe = Stream.of(foe_2).map(Mapper_1).map(Mapper_2).toArray(Foe::new);
```

in Mapper_1:

```
{
  System.out.println("Mapper_1");
  do stuff
}
```

in Mapper_2:

```
{
  System.out.println("Mapper_2");
  do other stuff
}
```

I need Mapper_1 to be finished before Mapper_2 starts.
The functions called by Mapper_1 and Mapper_2 do not call each other!

What I expected:
Mapper_1 maps all elements of the stream that `Stream.of(foe_2)` returns, then Mapper_2 maps to the output array, resulting in this output:

```
Mapper_1  
...  
Mapper_1  
Mapper_2  
...  
Mapper_2
```

What happens consistently:
Mapper_1 maps the first element of `Stream.of(foe_2)` and immediately after that, Mapper_2 takes this first result and maps it, ready to be put into the output array, before Mapper_1 maps the second element, resulting in this output:

```
Mapper_1  
Mapper_2  
NullpointerExcpetion
```

I get the Exception because Mapper_1 didn't map all elements and the data-structure is messed up.

Is this normal behavior, which would occur counter-intuitive to me, or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you share some more details on what Mapper_1 and Mapper_2 are supposed to do?

Comment: Mapper_1 loads some data.
Mapper_2 processes this data (builds kind of like a double linked list with 2 next and previous elements each), but needs all the data or else will run into nullpointers

Comment: Related: [Java 8 stream operations execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915591/java-8-stream-operations-execution-order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Streams process 1 element at a time, so the behaviour you are seeing is in fact required by the JDK spec.

To process all elements through mapper 1, *then* all elements through mapper 2, you need 2 streams one after the other and something to collect the first stream in the middle before passing elements to the second stream.

But don’t worry; you can express it in one line:

```
Foe[] foe = Stream.of(foe_2)
  .map(Mapper_1)
  .collect(toList()).stream()
  .map(Mapper_2)
  .toArray(Foe::new)
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you see is expected and even necessary as streams are potentially infinite. A stream only 'produces' an item when it is asked for an item by a terminal operation, and when that happens the entire chain of steps is executed for that individual item.

So when `toArray` is executed, it will ask the stream to produce the first item, which is mapped through `Mapper_1` and then `Mapper_2`, then the second item, which is mapped through `Mapper_1` and then `Mapper_2`, etc.

If you need `Mapper_1` to see all items before you go to `Mapper_2`, then you will need to collect into an intermediate collection or array before streaming that into `Mapper_2`.

For example

```
Foe[] foe = Stream.of(foe_2)
    .map(Mapper_1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .stream().map(Mapper_2)
    .toArray(Foe[]::new);
```

However, it would be better if your mappers are stateless and do not rely on seeing all items.

See also [Java 8 stream operations execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915591/java-8-stream-operations-execution-order)