# Assign Stream to a variable : Okay or Not?

Tags: java, java-stream

If I assign a stream to a variable e.g.

```
final Stream<String> docs = REST_CLIENT.postLS(RestClient.appendSegmentToPath(bucketUrl, "_bulk_get"),
```

Would this be a bad idea? Because the stream would require to store the data in memory - like a Collection does. But unlike a collection, a stream does not specify how to store the data - as an Array, Tree or else

Comment: Variable `docs` is a reference to a Stream, not its data, so "Because the stream would require to store the data in memory" makes no sense.

Comment: Nothing wrong with assigning a stream to a variable. I don’t think the need arises often, but occasionally. I might not want the variable to be final since once the stream is used, it cannot be used again, and carrying a useless stream in a final variable doesn’t seem to have any point to it.

Comment: A stream does not store data like a collection and regardless of whether it does or not, that wouldn’t change if you assign it to a variable. The semantic implications of assigning it to a variable instead of using it only fluently have been discussed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33746357/2711488).

Answer (score 5):

Streams are lazily evaluated they are not like a Collection which act as a holder of data. So in your code the `Stream<String>` is a source of `String` data and when you do stream operations and have a terminal operation then that stream pipeline would be evaluated and is said to be *consumed*, till that time no memory is used to store the data from the stream source.

This is as per the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed
>   when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are
>   consumed only as needed.
>
> Collections and streams, while bearing some superficial similarities,
>   have different goals. Collections are primarily concerned with the
>   efficient management of, and access to, their elements. By contrast,
>   streams do not provide a means to directly access or manipulate their
>   elements, and are instead concerned with declaratively describing
>   their source and the computational operations which will be performed
>   in aggregate on that source.

But once you have used a terminal operation on the Stream the Stream is consumed and cannot be used again. You need to get a new Stream from your source to do the same action.

For example lets get a `Stream<String>` and hold its reference in a variable:

```
Stream<String> stream  = Stream.of("foo", "bar");
stream.forEach(System.out::println); //invoke terminal operation
stream.forEach(System.out::println); // stream is already consumed
```

When you try to invoke the terminal operation again, you get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`

Answer (score 1):

**In here**

You cant docs stream again and again  because of A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once

```
final Stream<String> docs = REST_CLIENT.postLS(RestClient.appendSegmentToPath(bucketUrl, "_bulk_get"),
```

**In here**

You can use stream again and again , using Supplier

Supplier is an in-built functional interface introduced in Java8 in the java.util.function package. The supplier can be used in all contexts where there is no input but an output is expected. Since Supplier is a functional interface

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> docs =  REST_CLIENT.postLS(RestClient.appendSegmentToPath(bucketUrl, "_bulk_get"), 

docs.get()// you can perform operation after calling get().map().filter()
```