# Java 8 Stream - Use filter to add element to list

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm discovering java 8 streams.

Starting from a Map I'd like to get all matching values from the map key.

And I don't understand why that code

```
    Map<String,String> datas = new HashMap<String,String>();

    datas.put("x1","123");
    datas.put("x2","123");
    datas.put("x3","123");

    datas.put("Value_001_1","123");
    datas.put("Value_001_2","123");
    datas.put("Value_002_2","123");
    datas.put("Value_003_1","123");
    datas.put("Value_003_2","123");
    datas.put("Value_004_2","123");
    datas.put("Value_005_1","123");

    datas.put("y1","123");
    datas.put("y2","123");
    datas.put("y3","123");

    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    String expression = "Value_#Position#_1";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression.replaceAll("#Position#","(?<position>.*)"));

    datas.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(entry.getKey());
            if(matcher.matches())
            {
                results.add(matcher.group("position"));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

    System.out.println(results);
```

gives me

```
[]
```

but when using

```
    datas.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> {
          ... 
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

it gives me the expected result

```
[005, 001, 003]
```

or when using

```
    datas.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> {
          ... 
        })
        .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey()));
```

it also gives me the expected result

```
Value_005_1
Value_001_1
Value_003_1
[005, 001, 003]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219667/stream-and-lazy-evaluation

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no terminal operation in the example:

```
datas.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> { ...
```

and streams are driven by terminal operations (nothing will be done until a terminal operation is present). That is why your second example works, cause you have a terminal operation via `collect` or `forEach`.

Besides that, you are violating a rule of *side-effects*, basically a `filter` must not perform any actions outside of itself (like your are updating the `ArrayList`).

As usual Holger found a nicer way to do it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Value_(\\d+)_1");
List<String> results = datas.keySet().stream()
            .map(pattern::matcher)
            .filter(Matcher::matches)
            .map(m -> m.group(1))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  About your last remark, is there a nicer (and so not violating a rule of side-effects) way of doing the job ?

Comment: @tweetysat you could do this for example: `List<String> results = datas.keySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.matches("Value_(\\d+)_1"))
                .map(x -> x.replaceFirst("Value_(\\d+)_1", "$1"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @tweetysat or to apply the regex only once `List<String> results = datas.keySet()
                .stream()
                .map(x -> {
                    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(x);
                    if (m.matches()) {
                        return m.group(1);
                    }
                    return "";
                })
                .filter(x -> !x.isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Eugene: There is no need to introduce empty strings just to filter them later-on: `List<String> results = datas.keySet() .stream() .map(pattern::matcher) .filter(Matcher::matches) .map(m -> m.group(1)) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Holger awesome! I was somehow inclined towards this, but could not find the appropriate "words". thank u

Answer (score 1):

Streams in Java 8 have 2 types of operations, the intermediate operations and the terminal operations.

Intermediate operations are lazily evaluated which means, they are not executed till the time a stream ends with a terminal operations.

Terminal operations are forEach, collect, reduce etc etc..

you can do something like the following:

```
Stream createFilterStream(map,Predicate) {
return map.entryset.stream.filter(predicate)
}
```

not the actual code, but hopefully, you get the idea

the caller of the method can filter a map by the given predicate and then call the terminal function on it to use the results

```
createFilterStream(map, predicate).collect(<collection_logic>)
```