# Lazy evaluation of streams in Java: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

As per Java 8 API and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219667/stream-and-lazy-evaluation) , the streams are evaluated lazily. I have the following code snippet:

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList("d", "dw", "ew", "jj", "hh"); //Line 1
Stream<String> ls=l.stream();                                //Line 2
ls.map(a->a+"e");                                            //Line 3
ls.map(a->a+"de").foreach(System.out::println);              //Line 4
```

If streams are lazy, then, in my understanding, *ls.map* should return a new stream both the times i.e. line 3 and line 4 without really evaluating the lambda. When I run this piece of code, following is the output pointing error on Line 4:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

When I repeat this exercise with Iterators in Scala which are also lazy. I receive no such errors:

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4);
res1=a.iterator;    //Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
res2=res1.map(_+1); //Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
res3=res1.map(_+1); //Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
res3.foreach(println) //1,2,3,4
res2.foreach(println) //no output as the iterator has "traversedonce"
```

Regardless of my comparison with Scala, my basic focus is on the claimed laziness. Am I missing something when it comes to Java's Streams' implementation of laziness?

Comment: Apparently, line 3 has consumed the `Stream` so it isn't available in line 4 anymore... A `Stream` (in Java) is not comparable to the iteration of a `List` (in Scala).

Comment: `Stream#map` returns a new `Stream`; `ls.map(a->a+"e");` should be `ls = ls.map(a -> a + "e");`

Comment: @deHaar - Please check my code again...Its not a.map. Its a.iterator.map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` call on line 3 sets the `linkedOrConsumed` flag on `ls` to true.
This causes the error on line 4.

Even though the operation hasn't occurred yet, Java apparently won't allow you to redefine what you are going to do with the stream.