# What is the difference between a lazy operator and a stream capable one?

Tags: mule, dataweave

Certain functions and operations in DataWeave seem to execute in a lazy manner, not loading all records at once or only executing when called. At the same time, some seem to support streaming. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Interesting question. Could you please pass those function examples

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219667/stream-and-lazy-evaluation) help @afelisatti?

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming payload is streamcapable. it cannot be accessed more than once and we can access it only in a sequential manner.