# .map and mutation of original object's content

Tags: java, java-8

Consider this code

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(new Employee("A", "B"));
employees.add(new Employee("A1", "B1"));
    
employees.stream().map(e-> { e.setfName("Mr. " + e.getfName()); return e; }); // 1. DOES NOT mutate employees' content

employees.stream().map(e-> { e.setfName("Mr. " + e.getfName()); return e; }).collect(Collectors.toList()); // 2. DOES mutate employees' content

employees.stream().map(e-> new Employee ("Mrs. " + e.getfName(), e.getlName())).collect(Collectors.toList()); // 3. DOES NOT put new objects in original list
```

Not sure if I understand the reason for this behavior.  If the stream does create a separate memory, shouldn't 2 also NOT mutate the original list's content?

Answer (score 4):

```
employees.stream().map(e-> { e.setfName("Mr. " + e.getfName()); return e; }); // 1. DOES NOT mutate employees' content
```

Line 1 only doesn't mutate employees' content because it doesn't do anything at all.  Streams aren't evaluated until a terminal operation is called.

Line 2 creates a new list to hold the updated employees, but the original employees are updated -- so you have two independently modifiable lists that contain exactly the same employees with exactly the same data where you can't modify one without the other.  So with the result of line 2, you could `add` new `Employee` objects and not modify `employees`, but you couldn't modify the employees *in* that `List` without modifying the originals too (because they're the same employees).

Only Line 3 creates new `Employee` objects which exist independently of the originals.

Comment: Okay, that helped.  But how can I use .map to change the original collection items without ending up having a duplicate list?  e.g. Is there a terminal operation I can call without creating new list (e.g. like in Javascript).  Or am I completely off here in mis-using / comparing the .map with those of other dynamic/functional languages?

Comment: If your goal is to change the original collection items and not create a new list, then use `.forEach` instead of `.map`.

Comment: well, aren't we supposed to only put pure functions(lambdas) inside forEach? Which means not changing anything out of it's closure?

Comment: No.  The point of `forEach` is to do the opposite of that, to have only impure functions.  `map` is for pure functions.  By its definition, `forEach` does nothing whatsoever if passed a pure function.

Comment: I thought "pure function" restriction applied to all lambdas!  I am going through some tutorials on functional programming in java and thats what it seems to have been suggested.

Do you have some link from official source (maybe oracle) to suggest that .forEach is to be used with impure functions?

Comment: [Unlike most other functional interfaces, `Consumer` is expected to operate via side-effects.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html)  `Consumer` is the type of lambdas passed to `forEach`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks.

Comment: One another question, looks like I could use Line 3 to create shallow clone copy of a collection.  Is this a preferred or frowned-upon approach e.g. say compared to cloning or copy-constructors?

Comment: `clone()` is generally frowned upon.  Copy constructors are a little nicer.

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to understand about streams is [that they are lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21219667/5923139). If you `map` the values, the mapping function is only called when you retrieve values from the stream. `collect`ing a stream is one way to use the values and force the mutations, which is why the second example mutates the list and the first one doesn't. The third example doesn't mutate the objects in place, instead creating a new `Employee` for each one, so it creates a new cloned list that is unrelated to the original list.