# Why can do distinct() method at infinite stream in java

Tags: java, java-stream

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Random().ints(1, 45 + 1) // (1)
                .distinct()  // (2)
                .limit(6)
                .sorted()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

`new Random().ints` is infinite stream.

I guess, infinite stream can't distinct because infinite stream continues to grow.

but this code is possible.

how it works?

Comment: Because a stream is evaluated lazily and you limit the stream to `6` elements.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html): *"Streams are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are consumed only as needed."*

Comment: I think `.distinct()` keeps track of which elements it has seen internally, so it can work even if you don't limit the stream by just dropping already seen elements.

Answer (score 2):

Because of `.limit(6)` result isn't infinite.
Streams doesn't produce whole result on each operation.

Answer (score 2):

Streams are built on the concept of lazy evaluation. This means that each operator (`distinct` in your case) does not consume the complete stream of elements before the next operator is applied.

So each element of the stream is passed through all operators until it reaches a terminal operator. Then the next element of stream is passed through all operators again until it reaches a terminal operator. This is the reason your operator `distinct` is able to work on a provided as you say infinite stream.

`limit` is the terminal operator which is used in your case. You can observe how this works by intercepting the elements with `peek`. Check the following and you will be able to understand how streams work in a lazy concept as said before until they reach a terminal operator.

```
new Random().ints(1, 45 + 1) // (1)
                .peek(el -> System.out.println("Before distinct " + el))
                .distinct()  // (2)
                .peek(el -> System.out.println("After distinct " + el))
                .limit(6)
                .peek(el -> System.out.println("After limit " + el))
                .sorted()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Will print

```
Before distinct 8
After distinct 8
After limit 8
Before distinct 45
After distinct 45
After limit 45
Before distinct 16
After distinct 16
After limit 16
Before distinct 34
After distinct 34
After limit 34
Before distinct 9
After distinct 9
After limit 9
Before distinct 25
After distinct 25
After limit 25   <---- Here the limit of 6 elements is covered so the first stream is completed.
8
9
16
25
34
45
```

Also take a look on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68430419/java-streams-concat-streams-with-supplier-followed-by-distinct-lazy-evaluation/68430596#68430596) to see a similar investigation of the past.